# How do you a nested value ina multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, api, multidimensional-array, twitter

I am trying to learn Twitter's API. This is what the server returns when you send a request.

```
[
  {
    "coordinates": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "truncated": false,
    "created_at": "Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012",
    "id_str": "240859602684612608",
    "entities": {
      "urls": [
        {
          "expanded_url": "https://dev.twitter.com/blog/twitter-certified-products",
          "url": "https://t.co/MjJ8xAnT",
          "indices": [
            52,
            73
          ],
          "display_url": "dev.twitter.com/blog/twitter-c\u2026"
        }
      ],
      "hashtags": [

      ],
      ad infinitum...
```

My question is if the code I am using which works for non nested values is like this:

```
echo($tweets[$tweet_counter]['created_at']);
```

How do I access the url? I tried this:

```
echo($tweets[$tweet_counter]['entities']['urls']['url']);
```

Comment: You don't need to put variables in square brackets (`[...]`) when using `echo`, just `echo $tweets[$tweet_counter.....`

Comment: I edited it, I have parentheses for readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first decode your `json` to an associative array

```
$array = json_decode($json, true); //note the true as second parameter to have decoded as associative array
```

Then you can access values with scopes

```
$array['created_at'];
$array['entities']['urls']['url'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In that format and without having more information about your code, you can do the following:

**Object Format**

```
$Data = json_decode($your_json);
$Url = $Data[0]->entities->urls[0]->url;

echo $Url; // returns: https://t.co/MjJ8xAnT
```

**Explicit Array Format**

```
$Data = json_decode($your_json, TRUE); //<--- note the TRUE here
$Url = $Data[0]['entities']['urls'][0]['url'];

echo $Url; // returns: https://t.co/MjJ8xAnT
```